# Need advice on my newbie DIY repair plan for peeling paint/caulk on exterior window frame

Tags: painting, exterior, caulk

I'm a new home owner trying to get all of the information I need to tackle this project. I tend to overthink things, but I'm trying to do this the right way. Here's my plan, and I am hoping that someone can help guide me in the right direction if I have something wrong:

1. Clean and strip the sections of peeling/loose paint (5-in-one tool and sanding block or considering getting an oscillating multi tool with a sanding attachment to help)
2. Remove the old caulk at the seams (with a razor and/or scraper)
3. Re-caulk the seams around the window (Big Stretch is the product I'm considering, something for exterior and paintable)
4. Re-paint with 100% acrylic exterior paint & primer (Behr Premium Plus from Home Depot is what I'm looking at)

Thanks for any guidance!

*Edited per moderation advice, please disregard the arrows in the pictures below*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please take the [tour]. You've asked one question "does anyone know what this is?", then muddied the waters by talking about a process for refinishing that's unrelated to identifying what "this" is. Please [edit] this down to just asking the identification question, or get rid of that entirely (to match your title). In either case, feel free to ask the other question independently.

Answer (score 1):

The piece you point out looks like a PVC trim part -- it's just a plastic replacement for wood. Even if you break it, it's easy to replace, so don't worry too much about it.

Just scrape the paint that's peeling off, remove the caulk with a utility knife. Recaulk. Prime everything with a good-quality primer (this is more important than the paint itself.) Then make sure to use outdoor paint.

Give yourself plenty of time to do the job, and buy extra materials.

Answer (score 0):

The Vinyl part of the window only needs some cleaning,  some new caulking would help

However the wood part (frame) needs more attention.

Scrape the old pain and the caulking. Sanding might be needed.

If the wood is slightly damaged use special wood filler for rotten wood. Test the depth of the root by pushing a nail in it, by hand .

Apply fresh caulk and paint.